# Change DataGrid cell value programmatically in WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` view that fill it's content by a list in run time.
I want to change (For example) cell value in row:2 and column:3.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not that complicated.

You need helper functions;

```
public static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
{
    T child = default(T);
    int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
    {
        Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        child = v as T;
        if (child == null)
        {
            child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
        }
       if (child != null)
       {
           break;
       }
   }
       return child;
}

public static DataGridRow GetSelectedRow(this DataGrid grid)
{
    return (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(grid.SelectedItem);
}
public static DataGridRow GetRow(this DataGrid grid, int index)
{
    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
    if (row == null)
    {
        // May be virtualized, bring into view and try again.
        grid.UpdateLayout();
        grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.Items[index]);
        row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
    }
    return row;
}

public static DataGridCell GetCell(this DataGrid grid, DataGridRow row, int column)
{
    if (row != null)
    {
        DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);

        if (presenter == null)
        {
            grid.ScrollIntoView(row, grid.Columns[column]);
            presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
        }

        DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
        return cell;
    }
    return null;
}

public static DataGridCell GetCell(this DataGrid grid, int row, int column)
{
    DataGridRow rowContainer = grid.GetRow(row);
    return grid.GetCell(rowContainer, column);
}
```

Use yourDataGrid.GetCell(5, 3).Content = "whatever you want";

Comment: This is a joke, right? One used to need only one line to get/set the value of a Datagridview in Winforms!

Comment: @bodycountPP; unfortunately not. Although, the truth is, you should never change cell value programmatically - this is not what WPF is for, WPF is not winforms replacement or upgrade, it's a new innovation. Look into DataGridView and MVVM to see how things should be done in commercial applications.

Comment: GetVisualChild always returns null. Why is it?

Comment: This works but if you change a bunch of values the values change back to their original form as soon as you navigate away.  If you select the cell and scroll then scroll back it will retain the value you assigned but other cells will revert to their original value... strange.

Answer (score 2):

For example if you have TextBox on your grid

```
<TextBox  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding ...}"/>
```

Full sample

```
<Grid x:Name="RootElement">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      ...
      <TextBox  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding ...}"/>
      ...
    </Grid>
```

You can use these helpers; you have this link http://techiethings.blogspot.fr/2010/05/get-wpf-datagrid-row-and-cell.html.

Iadded the code in order to save code on stackoverflow, in the case where the site become closed

```
public static DataGridRow GetRow(this DataGrid grid, int index)
{
    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
    if (row == null)
    {
        // May be virtualized, bring into view and try again.
        grid.UpdateLayout();
        grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.Items[index]);
        row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
    }
    return row;
}

public static DataGridCell GetCell(this DataGrid grid, DataGridRow row, int column)
{
    if (row != null)
    {
        DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);

        if (presenter == null)
        {
            grid.ScrollIntoView(row, grid.Columns[column]);
            presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
        }

        DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
        return cell;
    }
    return null;
}

public static DataGridCell GetCell(this DataGrid grid, int row, int column)
{
    DataGridRow rowContainer = grid.GetRow(row);
    return grid.GetCell(rowContainer, column);
}
```

Comment: i want to do it programmatic,my selection is not static every time i select different cell,how can i do it?

Comment: every things is OK but when i move gw scroll up or down data will disappear.what's problem?