# Change Datagrid cell number of decimals

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, cell

I have a datagriId bound to an observable collection. I want to store the correct values in the observable collection (with all decimals) but I want to see less decimals in the datagrid.
So I tried this
[Change DataGrid cell value programmatically in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164079/change-datagrid-cell-value-programmatically-in-wpf)
and some similar others.

In the end what I need is to change the value of the datagrid when the event is fired.

```
private void Datagrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
  DataGridRow row = e.Row;
  var pePCDmise = row.Item as PcDmisData.Measures;

  DataGridRow rowContainer = dtgResults.GetRow(0);
  DataGridCell  d = dtgResults.GetCell(rowContainer, 3);
}
```

So the rowcontainer above is not null but when I try to get the cell value I get a null exception.
Particularly:

```
public static DataGridCell GetCell(this DataGrid grid, DataGridRow row, int column)
{
  if (row != null)
  {
    DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);

    if(presenter == null)
    {
      grid.ScrollIntoView(row, grid.Columns[column]);
      presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
    }

    DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
    return cell;
  }
  return null;
}
```

the presenter above is null and it's null also after having entered the if.

How can I make it work?
Thanx

---ADD----
Aside from the aforementioned problem how can I make a one-way-bind? I have set the datagrid bind with

```
 dtgResults.ItemsSource = easyRunData.olstMeasures;
```

but now I want to change the dtgResults number of decimals only and not the observable collection value.

Comment: Maybe it's better to write `ValueConverter` for this row, that rounds number of binded value

Comment: @bars222 How so? could you kindly provide a practival example. I am working from code-behind and as said have set dtgResults.ItemsSource = easyRunData.olstMeasures;. I thought that it was better working from Datagrid_LoadingRow since not all columns contains numbers to be properly set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to change DataGridCell value is to use `Loaded event handler` of `TextBlock` :

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Area, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"  Loaded="TextBlock_Loaded"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>



private void TextBlock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock tb = ((TextBlock)sender);

    // do anything with textblock    

    if (tb.Text == 10)
    {
        tb.Background = Brushes.Plum;
    }
}
```

If `AutogenerateColumns = true`, then we need to handle DataGridCell's Loaded event.

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
         <EventSetter Event="DataGridCell.Loaded" Handler="DataGridCell_Load"/>
     </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>

private void DataGridCell_Load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;

            if (cell.Column.Header.ToString() == "MyColumn")
                ((TextBlock)cell.Content).Text = ...do something... ;

            /* to get current row and column */
            DataGridColumn col = cell.Column;
            Dgrd2.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(cell);
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)Dgrd2.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(Dgrd2.CurrentItem);             
        }
```

Comment: That works but adds a new columns. I did that:  <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn >
                  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Area, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"  Loaded="TextBlock_Loaded"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
              </DataGrid.Columns>

Comment: Set AutoGenerateColumns = false

Comment: That takes off all the columns but the added one. How can I know from inside the TextBlock_Loaded what row and column I am referring to?

Comment: that worked thanx! But if I wanted to make it more general. That is: to call the same routine for different datagrids and then to switch according to the datagrid name. I tried cell.Parent. but that is always null...

Answer (score 0):

If you generating columns for `DataGrid` in code behind you can write something like this. Xaml part.

```
<DataGrid Name="dgTest" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
</DataGrid>
```

`ValueConverter` code. In examle I used rounding for 3 digits, but you can pass this as `ConverterParameter` and improve code.

```
public sealed class DecimalConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture )
    {
        double result = 0;
        if ( value is double )
            result = Math.Round( ( double )value, 2 );
        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture )
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Initializing code.

```
DataGridTextColumn valColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
Binding valBinding = new Binding( "SomeVal" );
valBinding.Converter = new DecimalConverter();
valColumn.Binding = valBinding;
dgTest.Columns.Add( valColumn );
dgTest.ItemsSource = Objects;
```

My test Observable collection is named `Objects` and containing objects with double property `SomeVal` and realization `INotifyPropertyChanged` behaviour.

```
private double _someVal;

public double SomeVal
{
    get { return _someVal; }
    set { _someVal = value; NotifyPropertyChanged( "SomeVal" ); }
}
```

**Update** Typical `INotifyPropertyChanged` realization.

```
#region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
#endregion
protected void NotifyPropertyChanged( String info )
{
    if ( PropertyChanged != null )
    {
        PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( info ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply. I am a newbye at wpf. So when I copy-pasted your code I got a build error on the word NotifyPropertyChanged. How can I fix it? And then I have various columns and have to use the converter only on 1-2-3  and not 0-4-... how can I do that? Thanx

Comment: 1 You should realize `INotifyPropertyChanged` behaviour.  2 You shoudn't add the converter into the binding for the 0-4-.. columns.