# set value in cell in datagrid in wpf in c#

Tags: wpf, datagrid

i want to set a value in a specific cell in wpf 
and i use this code but getRow and getCell method show this error

> 'DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'GetRow' and no extension method 'GetRow' accepting a first argument of type 'DataGrid' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> 'DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'GetCell' and no
>   extension method 'GetCell' accepting a first argument of type
>   'DataGrid' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)  ControlSolution.Form

and error in     public partial class UCfrmRaafaLevelsUp : UserControl

> Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

the code i use it

```
    public static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
{
    T child = default(T);
    int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
    {
        Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        child = v as T;
        if (child == null)
        {
            child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
        }
       if (child != null)
       {
           break;
       }
   }
       return child;
}

public static DataGridRow GetSelectedRow(this DataGrid grid)
{
    return (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(grid.SelectedItem);
}
public static DataGridRow GetRow(this DataGrid grid, int index)
{
    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
    if (row == null)
    {
        // May be virtualized, bring into view and try again.
        grid.UpdateLayout();
        grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.Items[index]);
        row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
    }
    return row;
}

public static DataGridCell GetCell(this DataGrid grid, DataGridRow row, int column)
{
    if (row != null)
    {
        DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);

        if (presenter == null)
        {
            grid.ScrollIntoView(row, grid.Columns[column]);
            presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
        }

        DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
        return cell;
    }
    return null;
}

public static DataGridCell GetCell(this DataGrid grid, int row, int column)
{
    DataGridRow rowContainer = grid.GetRow(row);
    return grid.GetCell(rowContainer, column);
}
```

in this post
[Change DataGrid cell value programmatically in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164079/change-datagrid-cell-value-programmatically-in-wpf)

Comment: As the error said, usually when you create extension methods you define a static class in a single file wherever you want, put the extension method in that class and then set a using where you want to use the extension methods to the namespace where your extension static class is put.

Comment: have there another answer???

Answer (score 2):

Extension methods are the static methods that are called as instance methods on the type they were created. eg: the GetCell() method that you created. It uses the reference of DataGrid to call this method.
Such methods must be defined in a separate static class. Put these methods GetSelectedRow, GetCell, GetRow in a different static class and the code should work.

Answer (score -1):

Extension methods need to be part of the inheritance chain. If your method is in a separate class (not DataGrid, and neither parent nor child of it), just make it normal static method, and call this method statically.

Logically, you cannot add an extension method to DataGrid itself nor its ancestor classes, and it doesn't seem like you are subclassing DataGrid, so this won't work.

Comment: @AhmedRabie, answer given by Shivani Katukota explains correctly what is Extension method and what you need to do to make the code work. Try it and if the answer helped you, mark it as accepted.