# null cell return when changing its background color

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a `DataGrid` where I want to retrieve the cell and change its content and its color when I perform a double-click.

The logical sequence is the following: I have my dates in a  `DataGrid`, they are white and without any content, when I double click it turns red and the content appears unavailable. If I click again it turns white again and its content empty.

I can leave it red, but when I click again and let it white, my function to fetch the cell returns `null`, even the value being valid. It only works when the cell is white.

```
private void gvPreV_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;

    int indexRow = dg.Items.IndexOf(dg.CurrentItem);
    int indexCol = dg.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;

    var cellInfo = new DataGridCellInfo(gvPreV.Items[indexRow], gvPreV.Columns[indexCol]);
    var cell = GetCell(cellInfo); // <~ return null when bg is red

    if (cell != null)
    {
        string aux = cell.Content.ToString();
        SolidColorBrush cor = null;

        if (aux == "unavailable")
        {
            cor = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 200, 57, 57));
            cell.Content = "";                  
         }
         else
         {
            cor = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 218, 57, 57));
            cell.Content = "unavailable";                   
         }
         cell.Background = cor;
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Error, Cell empty");
}



public DataGridCell GetCell(DataGridCellInfo cellInfo)
{
    var cellContent = cellInfo.Column.GetCellContent(cellInfo.Item);
    if (cellContent != null)
        return (DataGridCell)cellContent.Parent;
    return null;
}
```

How do I make the same cell as the unavailable value and background red go back to white when the double click occurs?
The `GetCell` method returns `null` when the position of a red unavailable cell is passed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your `GetCell` method, it can't find the corresponding `DataGridCell` anymore after the cell contents have been changed. If you implement the `GetCell` functionality as provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164079/change-datagrid-cell-value-programmatically-in-wpf), then you can use it like this:

```
var cell = dg.GetCell(indexRow, indexCol);
```

and all will work fine.